# GetViewForSupplementaryElement not getting called when trying to show heading in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, ios9

I am trying to setup a `UICollectionView` within my existing `UIViewController`. Everything is working except for getting a title to show for each section - I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My code in the `UIViewController` to initiate the collection view:

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    //...

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView_Outlet.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(ModifierCell), ModifierCell.CellID);
        CollectionView_Outlet.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView (typeof(Header), UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, Header.HeaderId);
        CollectionView_Outlet.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        CollectionView_Outlet.Source = new ModifiersSource(this);
        CollectionView_Outlet.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        CollectionView_Outlet.ReloadData();
    }

    //...
}
```

Then I have created a subclass of `UICollectionViewSource`:

```
public class ModifiersSource : UICollectionViewSource
{
    ViewController senderVC;

    public ModifiersSource(ViewController sender)
    {
        senderVC = sender;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return senderVC.modifiers.Count;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //...
    }


    public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var headerView = (Header)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView (elementKind, Header.HeaderId, indexPath);
        headerView.Text = "Supplementary View";
        return headerView;  
    }

}
```

And finally created:

```
public class Header : UICollectionReusableView
{
    public static NSString HeaderId = new NSString("UserSource1");
    UILabel label;

    public string Text {
        get {
            return label.Text;
        }
        set {
            label.Text = value;
            SetNeedsDisplay ();
        }
    }

    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public Header (RectangleF frame) : base (frame)
    {
        label = new UILabel (){
            Frame = new RectangleF(0,0,300,50), 
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red};
        AddSubview (label);
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    }
}
```

I've put a breakpoint on the `GetViewForSupplementaryElement` method but it never gets called. I've also set the following in my StoryBoard:

[image: XCode Screenshot]

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts of not being able to get the above to work, I manually set `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` whilst initiating the `UIContainerView`. Seems to have done the trick, but not sure why it didn't pick up the settings from my `StoryBoard`. Here is my working code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView_Outlet.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(ModifierCell), ModifierCell.CellID);
        CollectionView_Outlet.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(ItemOptionCell), ItemOptionCell.CellID);
        CollectionView_Outlet.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView (typeof(Header), UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, Header.HeaderId);
        CollectionView_Outlet.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;

        //This is the new bit I added:
        var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout ();
        layout.HeaderReferenceSize = new CGSize (300, 40);
        CollectionView_Outlet.SetCollectionViewLayout (layout, false);

        CollectionView_Outlet.Source = new ModifiersSource(this);
        CollectionView_Outlet.ReloadData();
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I am creating the collectionview programmatically and setting the headerreferenceisize and also using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and overriding GetReferenceSizeForHeader. Even doing that  GetViewForSupplementaryElement is not called. Still is it a bug in xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work in Xamarin, I had to enable Section Header under accessories (and it crashed in Xamarin, so from XCode). I had to do this even though I'm loading my header from a separate nib/xib into my collection view (but it will also show a reusable cell on the collection view that I don't think I need). Very specific but hopefully this saves someone in a similar situation some time!

Comment: While this is still a bug in Xamarin Studio (6.1.1 - Build 17) you can work around it but setting the Header Size in the Layout tab. Although the Section Header option remains unticked in the Accessories section of the 'Widget' tab the setting still appears to take effect.